# routesAreCached() method in Laravel undefined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-9

Please help me out a bit. I'm trying to setup passport for my Laravel app by following the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#introduction). But i'm stuck at the step where I need to check before calling `Passport::routes()`. My vscode displayed an error saying

> undefined method: routesAreCached()

even though when I traced back to the base abstract class ServiceProvider.php, the code there seems to be calling `$this->app->routesAreCached()` without any problems. Below is my App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The model to policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array<class-string, class-string>
     */
    protected $policies = [
        // 'App\Models\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        /**
         * This method will register the routes necessary to issue access tokens and revoke access tokens, clients, and personal access tokens:
         * 
         */

         if (! $this->app->routesAreCached()) {   // error at this line
            Passport::routes();
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: VSCode has issues detecting which classes/methods are available for Laravel projects. There are plugins available that help, like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client and https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper, or your can use a more robust PHP IDE, like PHPStorm, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passport's routes have been moved to a dedicated route file. You can remove the `Passport::routes()` call from your application's service provider.
[This link may help](https://github.com/laravel/passport/commit/a57723e58faaa70c5629d2a15f7ecc291e98fd73#diff-434625111321abb225365806085a3753cb854d098ed9b4b6dc2001235c7f7bc4R33)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    /** @var CachesRoutes $app */
    $app = $this->app;
    if (!$app->routesAreCached()) {
        Passport::routes();
    }
```

i hope it was useful !

Answer (score 1):

Use this , It will work

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    
    /** @var CachesRoutes $app */
    $app = $this->app;
    if (!$app->routesAreCached()) {
        Passport::routes();
    }
}
```